# Tree with dynamic data with checkboxes angular material

Tags: angular, angular-material, treeview

How to save selection in parents nodes when collapse checked children nodes with dynamic data.

Answer (score 0):

Could you please elaborate a bit more on the question. As far as what I could understand, you can try adding a boolean value in the node  structure of the  given element, bind that value using property binding, and execute a method on change or collapse event.

Comment: For example https://stackblitz.com/edit/material-tree-dynamic-bgmpaf?file=app/app.component.ts but data comes from the server

Answer (score 0):

First part I wrote how to query the data from the server, and the second part is about using this data with the selection methods.

I took your own answer and you only need to modify the functions in DynamicDatabase so you query your server to get the data and it works perfectly.

Let's say that you have a parent type of object IParent and a type of object IChild. Both have a id as part as their class.
You have your parent API and your children API which is of type

```
http://...../parents/[parent id]/childrens
```

so you need the parent id to get its children and this call returns an array of IChild objects.

```
export class DynamicFlatNode {
  constructor(
    public item: IParent | IChildren,
    public level = 1,
    public expandable = false,
    public isLoading = false,
  ) {}
}

/*Interface that extends IParent to keep also the children in the parent */
export interface IParentWithChildren extends IParent {
  children: IChild[]
}

/**
 * Database for dynamic data. When expanding a node in the tree, the data source will need to fetch
 * the descendants data from the database.
 */
@Injectable({ providedIn: 'root' })
export class DynamicDatabase implements OnDestroy {
  protected unsubscribe = new Subject();
  private parentMap = new Map<number, IParentWithChildren>();

  constructor(
    private parentApi: ParentApiService,
    private childApi: ChildApiService,

  ) {}

  public ngOnDestroy(): void {
    this.unsubscribe.next();
    this.unsubscribe.complete();
  }

  /** own functions */
  initialData(): Observable<DynamicFlatNode[]> {
    return this.parentApi
      .getAll()
      .pipe(takeUntil(this.unsubscribe))
      .pipe(
        map(
          (items: IParent[]) => {
            const newBaseNodes: DynamicFlatNode[] = [];
            items.map((p: IParent) => {
              parentMap.set(p.id, p);  
              newBaseNodes.push(new DynamicFlatNode(p, 0, true));
            });
            return newBaseNodes;
          },
          (error: string) => {
            //manage your error
            return [] as DynamicFlatNode[];
          }
        )
      );
  }

getChildren(node: DynamicFlatNode): Observable<IChild[]> {
    let itemsObs: Observable<IChild>[] = [];
    if (this.parentMap.get(node.item.id).children != null) {
      return of(this.parentMap.get(node.item.id).children);
    } else {
      return this.childrenApi
        .getAll(node.item.id)
        .pipe(takeUntil(this.unsubscribe))
        .pipe(
          tap((items: IChild[]) => {
            this.parentMap.get(node.item.id).children = items;
          })
        );
    }
  }
```

And finally you just need to change your function that calls getChildren so it does not work using a timeout but with the observable that getChildren returns

```
toggleNode(node: DynamicFlatNode, expand: boolean): void {
    const children = this._database.getChildren(node);
    const index = this.data.indexOf(node);
    if (!children || index < 0) {
      // If no children, or cannot find the node, no op
      return;
    }

    node.isLoading = true;

    if (expand) {
      const newLevel = node.level + 1;
      children.subscribe((items: IChild[]) => {
        const nodes: DynamicFlatNode[] = [];
        items.forEach((item: IChild) => {
          nodes.push(
            new DynamicFlatNode(
              item,
              newLevel,
              newLevel < 1,
              false,
            )
          );
        });
        this.data.splice(index + 1, 0, ...nodes);
        this.dataChange.next(this.data);
        node.isLoading = false;
      });
    } else {
      let count = 0;
      for (
        let i = index + 1;
        i < this.data.length && this.data[i].level > node.level;
        i++, count++
      ) {}
      this.data.splice(index + 1, count);
      this.dataChange.next(this.data);
      node.isLoading = false;
    }
  }
```

This should give you a tree with one parent level that is queried at the beginning and the children level queried on demand, being both 2 different types of objects. You could add a third level with another different type. Then in get children you should check the level to do one or another query and keep another map to avoid querying those items if the first time worked.

I used your stackblitz for my project (3 different levels with 3 different objects + selection) and I changed only the functions I stated before
https://stackblitz.com/edit/material-tree-dynamic-bgmpaf?file=app/app.component.ts

Therefore, the data is only removed from this.data to display/hide some nodes from the tree, but you could use your parentMap with children to add a field selected. Thus, you can iterate the parents map and if the parent has been selected, you check the children (you have to store a boolean too in the children). Finally, when a item is expanded, you have to re-set the checked status using the map.
I'm currently working on this to adapt it to my needs too, but at least that's the idea I have in mind.

**----Edit--------**

In order to do the selection with dynamic data, I end up removing all the SelectionModel by Angular Material as it is waay too complicated for what they want to achieve and not at all suitable for dynamic data. So I keep using a flat tree, but I added a parent and children fields to link a node to its ancestors and children. I also added a selected and indeterminate fields in the node so I can simplify the selection.

```
export class DynamicFlatNode {
  constructor(
    public item: IParent | IChild,
    public level = 1,
    public expandable = false,
    public isLoading = false,
    public parent: DynamicFlatNode = null,
    public children: DynamicFlatNode[] = null,
    public selected: boolean = false,
    public indeterminate?: boolean
  ) {}
}
```

You have to change slightly your toogleNode function to add those links

```
toggleNode(node: DynamicFlatNode, expand: boolean): void {
    
    if (index < 0) {
      // If cannot find the node, no op
      return;
    }
    node.isLoading = true;
    if (expand) {
      let nodes: DynamicFlatNode[] = [];
      if (node.children != null) {
        nodes = node.children;
        this.data.splice(index + 1, 0, ...nodes);
        this.dataChange.next(this.data);
        node.isLoading = false;
      } else {
        const children = this._database.getChildren(node);
        // If get children returns null is because there is
        // nothing to query (due to a call from handleTreeControl).
        if (children == null) return;
        const newLevel = node.level + 1;
        children.subscribe((items: IChild[]) => {
          items.forEach((item: IIChild) => {
            nodes.push(
              new DynamicFlatNode(item, newLevel, newLevel < 2, false, node)
            );
          }); // foreach
          node.children = nodes;
          this.data.splice(index + 1, 0, ...nodes);
          this.dataChange.next(this.data);
          node.isLoading = false;
        }); // subscribe
      }
    } else {
      // same as before
    }
  }
```

Finally, you remove all the selection functions from the tree component and replace them by your own selection functions to set the checkboxes. I leave you the code in a snippet.

In my case I end up doing a function when I change the root nodes (as I added pagination) so I expand the nodes that were selected once we go back to those root nodes. Therefore, I kept an internal id in the nodes and a map of the root selected nodes, so when I query new or already visited root nodes, I can set their children and selected info from my map.
I hope it helps.

```js
selectedLeafs: DynamicFlatNode<ITEM>[] = [];

  treeControl: FlatTreeControl<DynamicFlatNode<ITEM>>;

  dataSource: DynamicDataSource<ITEM>;

  constructor() {
    this.treeControl = new FlatTreeControl<DynamicFlatNode<ITEM>>(
      this.getLevel,
      this.isExpandable
    );
  }

  ngOnInit(): void {
    this.dataSource.setBaseNodes({
      limit: 1
    });
  }

  //checklistSelection = new SelectionModel<DynamicFlatNode<ITEM>>(true /* multiple */);

  getLevel = (node: DynamicFlatNode<ITEM>): number => node.level;

  isExpandable = (node: DynamicFlatNode<ITEM>): boolean => node.expandable;

  hasChild = (_: number, _nodeData: DynamicFlatNode<ITEM>): boolean =>
    _nodeData.expandable;

  /** selected methods */

  /**
   * Sets the leaf selection checkbox and updates the
   * selection status of its parents until the root.
   * @param node: Node clicked
   */
  leafItemSelection(node: DynamicFlatNode<ITEM>): void {
    node.selected = !node.selected;
    node.indeterminate = node.selected ? false : node.indeterminate;
    // check parent selected status with children
    this.checkSelectedStatusUpwards(node.parent);
    this.refreshSelectedLeafs(node);
  }

  /**
   * Sets the selection from the selection node to its children
   * until all the leafs are reached. Then it also checks the
   * parents of the node until the root as the status have been
   * modifed.
   * @param node: Node clicked
   */
  parentItemSelectionChange(node: DynamicFlatNode<ITEM>): void {
    this.triggerSelectedChangeTilLeafs(node, !node.selected);
    // also, check parent status til root.
    this.checkSelectedStatusUpwards(node.parent);
  }

  /**
   * Recursive function that sets the value passed by argument and
   * keeps setting this value in all the children.
   * @param node: Node to start the search
   * @param value: selected value
   */
  triggerSelectedChangeTilLeafs(
    node: DynamicFlatNode<ITEM>,
    value: boolean
  ): void {
    node.selected = value;
    if (node.children != null) {
      node.children.forEach((child: DynamicFlatNode<ITEM>) => {
        this.triggerSelectedChangeTilLeafs(child, node.selected);
      });
    } else {
      this.refreshSelectedLeafs(node);
    }
  }

  /**
   * It checks the status of its children to decide the selected status.
   * If all the children have a selected status, the parent has its checkbox to true
   * If all the children are not selected, the parent has its checkbox to false
   * Otherwise, it sets its status to indeterminate if there is a child with
   * status indeterminate or selected.
   * @param node: Node to start the search
   */
  checkSelectedStatusUpwards(node: DynamicFlatNode<ITEM>): void {
    if (node == null) return;
    if (node.children != null) {
      let allSelected = true;
      let noneSelected = true;
      let indeterminate = false;
      node.children.forEach((element: DynamicFlatNode<ITEM>) => {
        allSelected = allSelected && element.selected;
        noneSelected = noneSelected && !element.selected;
        indeterminate = indeterminate || element.selected || element.indeterminate;
      });
      if (allSelected) {
        node.selected = true;
        node.indeterminate = false;
      } else {
        node.selected = false;
        node.indeterminate = indeterminate;
      }
      if (node.parent != null) {
        this.checkSelectedStatusUpwards(node.parent);
      }
    }
  }

  /**
   * For a given leaf node that has changed its selected status, we update
   * the selectedLeafs array.
   * @param node : leaf node to check
   */
  private refreshSelectedLeafs(node: DynamicFlatNode<ITEM>): void {
    if (node.selected) {
      this.selectedLeafs.push(node);
    } else {
      const index = this.selectedLeafs.indexOf(node);
      if (index >= 0) {
        this.selectedLeafs.splice(index, 1);
      }
    }
  }

  /**
   * Pagination event that requires to change the root nodes.
   * @param event: pageEvent
   */
  public paginationEvent(event: PageEvent): void {
    this.dataSource.setBaseNodes({
      offset: event.pageIndex * event.pageSize,
      limit: event.pageSize
    });
  }
```

```html
<mat-tree [dataSource]="dataSource" [treeControl]="treeControl">
  <mat-tree-node
    *matTreeNodeDef="let node"
    matTreeNodeToggle
    matTreeNodePadding
  >
    <button mat-icon-button disabled></button>
    <mat-checkbox
      class="checklist-leaf-node"
      [checked]="node.selected"
      (change)="leafItemSelection(node)"
    >
    </mat-checkbox>
    <!-- child node -->
    <span class="title">{{node.item.name}}</span>
  </mat-tree-node>

  <mat-tree-node *matTreeNodeDef="let node; when: hasChild" matTreeNodePadding>
    <button
      mat-icon-button
      matTreeNodeToggle
      [attr.aria-label]="'Toggle ' + node.item"
    >
      <mat-icon class="mat-icon-rtl-mirror">
        {{treeControl.isExpanded(node) ? 'expand_more' : 'chevron_right'}}
      </mat-icon>
    </button>
    <mat-checkbox
      [checked]="node.selected"
      [indeterminate]="node.indeterminate"
      (change)="parentItemSelectionChange(node)"
      [disabled]='!treeControl.isExpanded(node)'
    ></mat-checkbox>
    <div class="info-container">
      <!-- parent nodes -->
      <span class="title"> {{node.item.name}} </span>
    <mat-progress-bar
      *ngIf="node.isLoading"
      mode="indeterminate"
      class="example-tree-progress-bar"
    ></mat-progress-bar>
  </mat-tree-node>
</mat-tree>
```